# Changing color of the GeometryDrawing Brush when Button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, system.windows.media, control-template

I created a Button Template. There are an Image and a Label.
The Source of the Image is in a ResourceDictionary Pictures. The Source of the picture is a DrawingImage with White brush color.

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="Moduly">
  <DrawingImage.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup>
      <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding BackgroundColor}" Geometry="M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0 Z " />
      <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding IconColor}" Geometry="M800.336 949.171H184.527c-80.603 0-136.768-65.56-136.768-146.159V203.677  c0-80.602 56.166-152.42 136.768-152.42h615.809c80.598 0 149.289 71.818 149.289 152.42v599.334  C949.625 883.611 880.934 949.171 800.336 949.171L800.336 949.171z M874.488 203.677c0-39.184-34.99-77.287-74.152-77.287H184.527  c-39.166 0-61.632 38.103-61.632 77.287v599.334c0 39.182 22.466 71.024 61.632 71.024h615.809  c39.162 0 74.152-31.843 74.152-71.024V203.677L874.488 203.677z M273.604 613.832h447.829v75.134H273.604V613.832L273.604 613.832z   M273.604 463.566h447.829v75.131H273.604V463.566L273.604 463.566z M273.604 313.295h447.829v75.134H273.604V313.295  L273.604 313.295z" />                   
    </DrawingGroup>
  </DrawingImage.Drawing>     
</DrawingImage>
```

The source of all styles (Button, StackPanel, Label) is in resource dictionary Styles.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 
  <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#103255"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Resources>        
      <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Style.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                           Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#103255" />
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>                
        </Style.Resources>
      </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#103255"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>                
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>        
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I need to change the brush color of the DrawingImage when the button is pressed. Only the specific one picture inside the pressed button.

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Name="modulyButton"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderThickness="3" Margin="0,0,0,0">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="modulyStackPanel"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image x:Name="modulyImage" Source="{StaticResource Moduly}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           Height="30" Width="30"/>
    <Label x:Name="modulyLabel" Content="MODULY"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I try create image style trigger. But there is problem. Image don't have color specification.

Comment: My next idea was to create drawingimage trigger directly inside resource dictionary Pictures. Using ancestor. But I don't know, if this is really possible.

Comment: I would like to send "color" to "source" as variable, from ancestor. If there is some better solution for using DrawingImage than Image.

Comment: Please share some code, this is not a free-code fabric. If we see your code it's simpler to help you.

Comment: Pavel, don't post a screenshot of your code. EMBED your code in your question, you have the button to format a section of text as code, and I'm pretty sure you have already seen many other StackOverflow questions with clear code sections.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus I upload screen of Styles. Upward. My button:

Comment: @Clemens  
I'm so sorry. I added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no way, with the structure you created. At compile time the `Image` of the `Button` knows only that a `StaticResource` of the correct type has been assigned to its `Source` property, but it doesn't know that the `Source` instance has a `DrawingGroup` with 2 elements which have a `Brush` property, and so there is no way to call that `Brush` property in the `Image.Triggers`.
You have to substitute the whole `DrawingImage`.

My solution (in a simplified form, with Green/Red color switch):

1) Create two `DrawingImage`, with the same `Geometry` but different `Brush`:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="Moduly1">
  <DrawingImage.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup>
      <GeometryDrawing Brush="Green" Geometry="M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0 Z" />
    </DrawingGroup>
  </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>

<DrawingImage x:Key="Moduly2">
  <DrawingImage.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup>
      <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red" Geometry="M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0 Z" />
    </DrawingGroup>
  </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

2) In the `Button` `Template` (in the `ResourceDictionary`) write this on the inner `StackPanel` style:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#103255" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <!-- ADDED PART -->
    <Style TargetType="Image">
      <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Moduly1}"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Moduly2}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <!-- END ADDED PART -->
  </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

3) In the particular instance of you `Button`, remove the `Source` property from the `Image` element.

Comment: Thank you. I try your solution and it works! But I have more than one button. I need more general solution. Maybe I should replace Image by ViewBox? In one example I saw there is possibility to fill Path with Binding Color and Source.

Comment: I guess you want many Buttons all with the same template (a Label and an Image, with that Style, layout, margins, etc), and you want only to change the Label Text and the Image Source from Button to Button (and the command bound to the Button). If you don't want to repeat the xaml of the template every time, I would suggest you to create a UserControl with the code of the Button and with some [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914) (like "TextProperty" and "ImageSourceProperty", or whatever), binding these with the properties of the internal components of the UC